# Choose random structs from vector of structs

Tags: c++, random, vector, struct

I have a vector of structs:

```
struct entries 
{
   double km1, km2, km3;
};
```

I've stored the structs in a vector. I'd like to choose 2 random structs from the vector and display each element of the randomly chosen structs: km1, km2, km3

I found a similar question on stackoverflow, but it was for a vector of ints and didnt return random structs for some reason. Thanks

Comment: Do the two structs have to be different, or can the random selection choose the same struct value for both?

Comment: @cdhowie they would need to be different because i'm choosing clusters for a k-means algorithm

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza can we use ``rand()``

Comment: @Winestone yes we can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the two is rather easy:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Engine>
std::tuple<Iterator, Iterator> pick_two(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Engine & engine)
{
    int size = end - begin;

    if (size < 2) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Sequence does not contain two elements");
    }

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, size - 1);

    int first = distribution(engine);
    int second;

    do {
        second = distribution(engine);
    } while (first == second);

    return std::make_tuple(begin + first, begin + second);
}
```

You can call it like this, given a global `std::default_random_engine random_engine;`, and a vector called `v`:

```
auto choices = pick_two(v.begin(), v.end(), engine);
```

You can get the first struct value with `*(std::get<0>(choices))` and the second with `*(std::get<1>(choices))`, and output the values using whatever method you prefer.

Comment: thanks, any idea what headers to include? getting stuff like: default_random_engine in namespace std does not name a type
, error: uniform_int_distribution is not a member of std, error: engine was not declared in this scope, error: unable to deduce auto from <expression error>

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza ``#include <random>`` I think

Comment: @winestone yea i included random. i want to give this a check mark i just can't get the code to compile

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza Each time that `std::default_random_engine` is default-constructed it is allowed to start with the same state.  Consider creating *one* such object for the entire program (assuming you are not multi-threaded) and using it repeatedly.

Comment: way above my expertise but i'll figure it out eventually. thanks

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza Basically, if you make a global variable `std::default_random_engine engine;` and then use that everywhere, you won't get the same result every time.